# Jenkins pipeline script to copy artifacts of current build to server location

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to create a Jenkins job which does following:
Git>Mvn build>  copy jar to some location of server.

So this can be done using a single job or 2 jobs?
Or which is preferred way of doing this , is pipeline preferred over creating a maven job?

I have created this pipeline script, but this does not copy the current build jar to the server location, it copies the previous build artifact jar.

```
node {
   def mvnHome
   stage('Preparation') { // for display purposes
      // Get some code from a GitHub repository
  git 'git@github.pie.ABC.com:abcdef/BoltRepo.git'
   mvnHome = tool 'M2'
   }
   stage('Build') {
      // Run the maven build
      if (isUnix()) {
         sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean     package"
      } else {
         bat(/"${mvnHome}binmvn" -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean     package/)
      }
   }
   stage('Results') {
      archiveArtifacts 'target/*/BoltRepo*.jar'
   }

   stage('Deploy Artifact') {
    copyArtifacts(
          projectName: currentBuild.projectName,
          filter: 'target/*/BoltRepo*.jar',
          fingerprintArtifacts: true,
          target:     '/ngs/app/boltd/bolt/bolt_components/bolt_provision/test',
          flatten: true        )
   }
 }


What is the best way of achieving this.
```

Comment: The [Copy Artifact plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact) which provides the `copyArtifacts` build step is for copying artifacts *from* another project.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the pipeline before, but I have done what you want using "ArtifactDeployer" from the "Post-build Actions" in the job's configurations 
Note: you will need to install "Artifact Deployer Plug-in"

Comment: Thanks or your reply. I just installed this plugin as suggested by you. And in 'Artifacts to deploy" section we shall mention the target directory? how to know what location to specify for specifying current build jar?

Comment: how do you specify the Remote File Location ? with serverName:pathToCopy? Does it require FTP user?

Comment: the jar path is projectName/target/*.jar

Comment: for the remote file location, I actually tried to deploy it on the same server machine jenkins is installed on, so I added the path as "/home/userName/FolderYouWantToDeployIn" , I didn't try to make it on a different server